# I want get the last four characters of the string

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to get the last four characters from a String, but every time I input something I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Please help me to solve this error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//need for Scanner
import java.io.*;
public class PansiyuA3Q2 {


  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception { 
    Scanner autoFile = new Scanner(new File("AutoCorrectMe.txt"));
   String a =getFileName();
  }
  static String getFileName(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//need for Scanner
    String a ="";//variable a
    String change = "";//get the last four character
    boolean valud ;//boolean valud
    int length = a.length();
    do{
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");//print Enter the name of the file:
       a= keyboard.nextLine();//get from user
       change = a.substring(length-4,length);
      if(change.equalsIgnoreCase(".txt"))//a equal autocrrectme.txt and ignore capital
        valud = true;//get true
      else //if a equal atuocorrectme and ignore capital
        System.out.println("The file name must end with .txt");//print The file name must end with .txt
      valud = false;//get false
    } while(!valud);//do while
    return a; 
  }//method getFilName

}
```

I can compile it but when I run the program ,whatever the word I input it says there is a error.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at PansiyuA3Q2.getFileName(PansiyuA3Q2.java:22)
    at PansiyuA3Q2.main(PansiyuA3Q2.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: Then what? Did you just give up when you saw the exception? What did your debugging turn up? Don't just dump your programs here. Explain what the problem is and why it happens.

Comment: Length of a is 0. Run the debugger and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Or think about where the number -4 in the stack trace has to come from.

Comment: You're assigning `length` from the initial value of `a`, which is `""`. Move `int length = a.length();` to _after_ `a= keyboard.nextLine();`. You will also need to add checking for cases where `a` has a length of less than 4, or you'll get similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

You declare and initialize `length` before you get the `a` from the user.

```
// int length = a.length();
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
    a = keyboard.nextLine();//get from user
    int length = a.length();
    if (length < 4) {
        continue; // <-- reloop if less then 4.
    }
```